# color coding mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, colors

how do i get the mac terminal to display colors? i.e. in fedora when i use `ls` it color codes the results based on if it's a file or folder. similar results on mac?

Comment: Edited question, since the answers suggest the problem is ls specific.

Comment: Can you provide examples other than `ls` which you'd like to have colorized and in what way? There are various colorizers that can be used in pipelines to highlight text based on regexes either in config files or on the command line.

Comment: in VI or VIM, especially in syntax coloring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your shell colors in Terminal's preferences.

[image]

---

With these settings, you get these colors (not usually using colored `ls`, so I don't care):

[image]

---

I don't understand what the issue is here. *Colored command output is active by default*. The only thing you can/need to do yourself is give normal and bold text different default colors, and actually use the colored variants (e.g. `ls -G`) of your commands.

For vim: `:syntax on` in `vim`. Or append `syntax on` to `.vimrc`.

Comment: display ANSI colors?

Comment: @tekknolagi This option enables colored output e.g. of `ls -G`. Toggle it with a Terminal window open to see the effect. You can also select different default colors for regular and bold text.

Answer (score 14):

Add, these lines to the end of your `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias ls='ls -G'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

As you can see, customizing them is a bit of a pain, but there's a website that helps with that... http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

Now when you open the Terminal it will have colors in `ls`

Comment: do i have to do that for every single command i want?

Comment: No, your `~/.bash_profile` is used to add settings to your Terminal sessions, it is loaded every time a Terminal window is shown. It's a text file, you just add those lines to the end, and save it. Then start up Terminal, or restart it, and your settings are active.

Comment: not what i meant. if i want to color code other commands

Comment: i am very familiar with the bash profile

Comment: Only if they have their own color profile, which commands are you interested in?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-G` switch to `ls` on Mac:

```
ls -G
```

If you'd like the standard ls to always be colored, add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```